# How can I get my MK808 mini Android PC to output to my TV?

Tags: hdmi, android-mini-pc

I had [this mini pc](http://www.sainsmart.com/android-mini-pc/sainsmart-ss808-pc-on-a-stick-for-android-4-1-dual-core-1-6-ghz-a9-processor-1gb-ddr3-8gb-internal-storage-dual-wifi-module-on-board.html) from a friend. But I cannot power it up.

When I connect it to TV with HDMI cable, the light is blue, but I got nothing show on the TV screen. I've tried some different HDMI cables, but it will not put a picture out to the TV.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Did you check if the HDMI cable is ok (by connecting a different device to your TV)?

Comment: I've tried some different HDMI cables. But it will not put a picture out to the TV.

Comment: My MK802 defaults to 720p60 (an unusual choice) when it first starts up, so you may want to check that your TV supports whatever mode your MK808 defaults to. How long have you waited for it to boot? If you are expecting instant-on you may be disappointed. *8')

Answer (score 1):

Its the resolution setting. That or your tv/monitor doesn't support the default setting. I was switching mine to all the different sizes and switched it to one my monitor didn't support. Was a total pain to switch back as I flipped it to some off size. Just try every tv/monitor you can find until it comes up. I have noted on a few occasions, it doesn't seem like its booting up right away, I had to unplug and wait a minute, then retry.